# Compute multiple queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 queries, the first one is like this

```
SELECT amount FROM table1
WHERE id = "1"
```

the output of this is

```
amount
10000
```

then my second query

```
SELECT SUM(hours * 10) as hours FROM table2
WHERE empid = "1"
```

output is

```
hours
400
```

and then my third query

```
SELECT totalcost FROM table3
WHERE id = "1"
```

output

```
totalcost
5000
```

I added the value of the second and third query

```
SELECT 'SUMQ2Q3',
(SELECT SUM(hours * 10) as hours FROM table2
WHERE empid = "1")

+

(SELECT totalcost FROM table3
WHERE id = "1")
```

and got the output of

```
5400
```

Next thing that I want to happen is to minus the value of the first query to the output i got when i sum the second and third query.
But i keep on getting a syntax error. It currently looks like this

```
SELECT amount FROM table1
WHERE id = "1"

-

SELECT
(SELECT SUM(hours * 10) as hours FROM table2
WHERE empid = "1"

+

SELECT totalcost FROM table3
WHERE id = "1")
```

How is the right way to do this?

Comment: Just write `WHERE id = 1` for integer comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no DB here, but

```
SELECT t1.amount - t2.sum + t3.totalcost
FROM (SELECT amount FROM table1 WHERE id = "1") as t1, 
     (SELECT SUM(hours * 10) as hours FROM table2 WHERE empid = "1") as t2
     (SELECT totalcost FROM table3 WHERE id = "1") as t3
```

might do the job.

Comment: i did it like this, just changed it to `SELECT t1.amount - (t2.sum + t3.totalcost)` it worked. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

How about trying

```
SELECT
    (SELECT amount FROM table1 WHERE id = "1")
    - (SELECT SUM(hours * 10) as hours FROM table2 WHERE empid = "1")
    - (SELECT totalcost FROM table3 WHERE id = "1")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (
(
SELECT amount FROM table1 WHERE id = "1") As x -
(SELECT SUM(hours * 10) as hours FROM table2 WHERE empid = "1") As y +
(SELECT totalcost FROM table3 WHERE id = "1") As z
)
As answer
```